# SQL service and database check with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate to serialize and store my java objects. 
I would like to check if SQL service is running and if the database is present before them.

How to do?

I have seen some method calling SQL function, but I'm looking something more integrated with hibernate, which read hibernate.cfg.xml for parameters (ex. DB name).